# Node.js - Typical callback issue

Tags: javascript, node.js

I added some comments into the code so that you can see what the issue is, basically... I want currency to be 'usable' after the db.where() function so that it can be used in the if statement. This'll no doubt be simple enough to fix, but I'm terrible. Thank you for your time.

```
db.where('users', {name: user.username}).then(function(result) {
    var currency = result.items[0].currency;
    console.log(currency);
});
console.log("Program gets to this point without error.");
console.log(currency); // Doesn't work as currency is no longer defined.
if (typeof args[2] == 'number' && args[2] <= currency) {
    var betOkay = true;
    console.log("betOkay is " + betOkay);
}
```

Comment: Stick the work you need to do inside the callback function...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to move your code into the callback or another function that you call from your callback. The callback is executed asynchronously, so it's not that `currency` is *no longer* defined, but it's that it's not defined *yet* and it's not in the same scope.

Comment: I put the code within the callback and for some reason it still doesn't get past the if statement. To clarify, args[2] is being provided as the number 1 and my currency is 73.

Comment: The console.log for betOkay isn't ran. The last thing executed is console.log(currency);

Comment: You should verify your value for `args` by doing a simple `console.dir(args);`

Answer (score 1):

You should use currency in callback.

```js
db.where('users', {name: user.username}).then(function(result) {
    var currency = result.items[0].currency;
    console.log(currency);
    if (typeof args[2] == 'number' && args[2] <= currency) {
        var betOkay = true;
        console.log("betOkay is " + betOkay);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has function scope. Variables are available within the function they are defined. But JavaScript also has closures which allow inner functions access to variables defined in the outer functions (see [JavaScript closures](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/)).

The variable *currency* is defined in the anonymous function you're using for your callback. So its scope is the callback function. This is why is not accessible elsewhere.

As the other answers indicate you can achieve your goal by including the code that needs to access currency within the callback but you can also declare the variable *currency* in the outer scope and set it (via closure) on the callback.

See below:

```js
var currency; // defined in the scope where it will be used

db.where('users', {name: user.username}).then(function(result) {
    currency = result.items[0].currency; // has access to it via closure
    console.log(currency);
});
console.log("Program gets to this point without error.");
console.log(currency); 
if (typeof args[2] == 'number' && args[2] <= currency) {
    var betOkay = true;
    console.log("betOkay is " + betOkay);
}
```